# Parallel insert into a partitioned table is running slower compared to a single insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, partition, sql-server-2016-express

When I run a single query( SELECT GROUP BY and INSERT ) it takes around 18 min( reducing 185 million to 11.5 million rows ) to complete the execution. If I run the same query 10 times as a parallel insert( SELECT GROUP BY and INSERT ) into a partitioned table spread across 10 file groups present in 3 different file systems( available memorey more than 1 TB in all 3 file systems. ) then the queries are running very long more than 2 hrs to complete. When doing the parallel insert the data is read from 10 different tables and inserted into the partitioned table.( SELECT GROUP BY query is the same for all 10 slices. ) Can somebody share your inputs why the queries are running longer even though the table is partitioned? The system configuration is the same for both scenarios I mentioned above. Let me know if any questions.

Note :- No other queries were running in background for both the scenarios mentioned above. I have set MAXDOP=0 when running the queries.

Comment: Are there indexes on the partitioned table?  Do the files containing the filegroups trigger autogrowth?

Comment: There are no indexes on the input source tables as well as the partitioned table.... And the file groups are pre grown to the size of the input table...

Comment: Are you using the TABLOCK hint?

Comment: No. TABLOCK on the table data is being read from?

Comment: I am loading into 10 different tables by reading data from 10 different tables... Why do I need TABLOCK in this case?

Comment: To use parallelism you must use "INSERT INTO [Table1] WITH (TABLOCK) SELECT * FROM.. "
Check compatibility is 130 also. The execution plan will clearly say if parallelism is working.

Comment: It really didn't help much with and without TABLOCK.

Comment: Was parallelism in the execution plan?

Comment: Yes I used MAXDOP=0